# Mail catcher not working PHP

Tags: php, email, mailcatcher

After a long time i still cannot catch mails via mailcatcher. Mail is sent, but it is not cought. I'm using xampp, and here are my settings in php.ini:

```
SMTP = localhost
smtp_port = 1025
sendmail_path = /usr/bin/env catchmail -f some@from.address
```

and PHP

```
$message = "Line 1\r\nLine 2\r\nLine 3";


$message = wordwrap($message, 70, "\r\n");


$sent = mail('caffeinated@example.com', 'My Subject', $message,'webmaster@example.com');

if($sent) {
    echo "<h1>Sent...</h1>";
}
```

#### UPDATE

I am testing this on Windows OS

Comment: basic debugging: did you check the return value from `mail()`? and note that `smtp` and `smtp_port` are for windows only. they're ignored on linux.

Comment: As you see from the code, if mail returns true it is sent and will echo "Sent..." . I am on windows, forgot to mention that.

Comment: if yiou're on windows, then why are you using a unix/linux path? `/usr/bin/env` doesn't exist in windoze...

Comment: Well that was dumb of me not looking at that. Just deleted that path and it worked like a charm. Too much copy paste. Thanks a lot !